# String appending function (location-independent)

Tags: c, strings, memory-management

Very useful operation that hasn't been merged into a function.. until now.
This is supposed to insert a substring into a previously d.allocated source string.

```
void strapp (char *source_offset, int position, char *appendage)
{
    size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage) + 1;

    char copy[strlen(source_offset)];
    strcpy(copy, source_offset);

    source_offset = realloc(source_offset, strlen(source_offset) + appendage_size);
    memcpy(&source_offset[position], appendage, strlen(appendage));
    sprintf(source_offset + (position + strlen(appendage)), &copy[position]);
}
```

---

**USAGE:**

```
int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = malloc(11 + 1);

    sprintf(str1, "Hello World");

    strapp(str1, 5, " Horrible");

    printf(str1);
    free(str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output:

`Hello Horrible World`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a string-inserting function than a string-appending function, and should be renamed as such.

When calling `realloc(…)`, the string could very well move to a different memory location.  The caller of `strapp()` has no way of knowing where the new string is, though.  Furthermore, if the string got moved, and the caller continues to use the string as if were still at `source_offset`, then that's a memory-use-after-free bug.

There are two possible remedies:

```
/**
 * s points to the address of the old and new string.
 */
string_insert(char **s, int insertion_pt, const char *to_insert)
```

or

```
/**
 * Returns the location of the new string, which may or may not be at
 * the original s.  Callers must assume that the string at s may be
 * invalid after this call.
 */
char *string_insert(char *s, int insertion_pt, const char *to_insert)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    sprintf(source_offset + (position + strlen(appendage)), &copy[position]);
```

may produce an undefined behavior if a trailing part of the source string has embedded `%` characters. Either use an explicit format string

```
    sprintf(source_offset + (position + strlen(appendage)), "%s", &copy[position]);
```

or `memcpy` it.